# Set onClickListener via MainActivity on an item in a ListAdapter

Tags: java, android, listview, listener, android-arrayadapter

How can I create a custom setOnClickListener for my class?

I currently have a listAdapter with items (Made a Item Class). Whenever I click on a item in that list, I want to activate the the functionality that I described in my MainActivity. I would like to set onClickListeners (custom onClickListeners) on classes that I have in my list adapter. How can I do so?

If you did not understand me, or would like to help, I zipped the project and put it on my [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxDxrRTCfsMpSEktc0hMMUF6cXc/view?usp=sharing)

I've looked through dozens of answer, but I just couldn't find the one that was working.. Please help, as I've invested way to much time in this.

```
Item item = new Item().setOnClickListener(new ItemListAdapter.ClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick() {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Clicked me", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

**EDIT: Because I would like to later turn it into a library, it would be useful for me and the user that you can set a onclick on a item rather than the listview, which I want to hide from the user eventually**

Comment: what do you want to do with logic exactly?

Comment: I've edited my question, maybe that explains what I exactly want

Comment: Why did you implement ClickListener in the activity? Is any reason for that?

Comment: That was the only thing I could think of in terms of custom listeners. I forgot that there is a onItemClickListener, and made this instead.

Comment: Can you check my answer and tell me whether it is working or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding you are looking for some thing like this , Change the class like this ,

```
public class Item {

    private int id;
    private ItemListAdapter.ClickListener mClickListener;

    public Item(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    public Item(int id, @NonNull ItemListAdapter.ClickListener clickListener) {
        this.id = id;
        this.mClickListener = clickListener;
    }


    public Item setOnClickListener(@NonNull ItemListAdapter.ClickListener clickListener) {
        this.mClickListener = clickListener;
        return this;
    }


    public ItemListAdapter.ClickListener getClickListener() {
        return this.mClickListener;
    }

}
```

Adapter class

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class ItemListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {


    public ItemListAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
        super(context, resource, SettingsStorage.getInstance().getItems());
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
        }

        final Item item = getItem(position);
        LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item);
        linearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (item.getClickListener() != null) {
                    item.getClickListener().onClick();
                }
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

    public interface ClickListener {
        void onClick();
    }
}
```

and you can set the listener like this ,

```
Item item1 = new Item(1);
        item1.setOnClickListener(new ItemListAdapter.ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick() {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "It works", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        Item item2 = new Item(2, new ItemListAdapter.ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick() {

            }
        });
```

Comment: You. Are. My. Hero. Thank you so much! I've wasted the past 2 weeks on this, and you solve it for me! I can't thank you enough!

Comment: but i would recommend to pass the item in the click listener.

Comment: Okay! Will look at it tomorrow (it's almost 12pm), thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `OnItemClickListener` :

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Item item = adapter.getItem(position);
    }
});
```

**EDIT :** 
The is that `Item` is just a POJO, you can't "click" on it. What you can do is kind of "forwarding" the listener :

```
Class Item {
    private ItemClickListener listener;

    // getter / setter

    interface ItemClickListener{
        void onItemClick(Item item);
    }
}

// you implement this in your library
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Item item = adapter.getItem(position);
        item.getListener().onItemClick(item);
    }
});
```

Comment: I know, but as it will result in a library, I would like the option of doing item.setOnClickListener rather than the user accessing the listview itself

Comment: I've seen other library's do that same thing, but I can't seem to reproduce.. for example "material drawer" from Mike penz.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set click listener to the whole row then "OnItemClickListner" is the option you are looking for.

Check this: [ListView with OnItemClickListener android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7645880/listview-with-onitemclicklistener-android)

But if you want to set click listener on one of the item of the row then first you have to get that item from row and then you can do whatever you want.

Check this: [ListView with OnItemClickListener android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7645880/listview-with-onitemclicklistener-android)

[Get list of items in custom adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24047288/get-list-of-items-in-custom-adapter)