# Does the ArrayAdapter have a method that returns the whole List that was passed to it in the constructor?

Tags: android, adapter, android-arrayadapter, android-adapter

I learned that you should not save the List or the Context in a custom ArrayAdapter field, because after passing them to the super method like this:

```
public CountryAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<CountryItem> countryList) {
    super(context, 0, countryList);
}
```

we can access these values with `getContext` and `getItem(position)`. But in my case I need the whole List in my custom adapter, and not just a single item. I didn't find a method that returns the List, does that mean I have to create a member variable for my List?

Comment: _you should not save the List or the Context in a custom ArrayAdapter field_ you can do it if you want

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Florian, you can create a member variable to store countryList and fetch it anytime through adapter's instance.Can you refer to some post or link which states otherwise?

This might be helpful as well [Get list of items in custom adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24047288/get-list-of-items-in-custom-adapter)

Comment: The op asked about ArrayAdapter.

Answer (score 0):

Arrayadapter **doesn't have any method** to return the list.

And in arrayadapter, the list is **private**

```
private List<T> mObjects;
```

If you want that list, Just store it in your **child adapter class field**. `//CountryAdapter`

> I learned that you should not save the List or the Context in a custom
>   ArrayAdapter field

You can access the list and context in your adapter class. It **will not affect** the super class method call.

*EDIT*

If you have any problem with storing the list, You can *use reflection method* to get ArrayAdapter's list field (`mObjects`). But it is not recommended and needed. Just store it in your adapter